# Are open $\mathbb{G}_m$-invariant subschemes of an affine scheme precisely the homogeneous radical ideals of its coordinate ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, graded-rings, group-schemes

I have a bunch of questions regarding actions of a group scheme $G$ on a scheme $X$. I'm fine with assuming $G$ affine.
$\newcommand{\IG}{\mathbb{G}}
\newcommand{\pmo}{{\pm 1}}
\newcommand{\IZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Spec}{\mathrm{Spec}}
\newcommand{\tensor}{\otimes}
\newcommand{\into}{\hookrightarrow}
\newcommand{\iso}{\cong}
\newcommand{\onto}{\twoheadrightarrow}
\newcommand{\sheaf}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\inv}{{-1}}$

Originally, I was thinking about actions of the multiplicative group $\IG_m = \Spec(\IZ[T^\pmo])$ on affine schemes $X = \Spec(R)$. The category of affine schemes with a $\IG_m$-action is equivalent to the category of $\IZ$-graded rings as follows:

To a $\IZ$-graded ring $R$ associate the action $\IG_m \times \Spec(R) \to \Spec(R)$ which is given by the map of rings $R \to \IZ[T^\pmo] \tensor R$, $f = \sum f_d \mapsto \sum f_d \tensor T^d$, where $f_d$ are the homogenous components of $f$. Conversely, if the action $\IG_m \times \Spec(R) \to \Spec(R)$ is given, call $f_d \in R$ homogenous of degree $d$ if it is sent to a homogenous element of rank $d$ by the morphism $R \to \IZ[T^\pmo] \tensor R \cong R[T^\pmo]$, where we regard the latter ring as graded by the powers of $T$.

If $Y \subseteq X$ is a closed subscheme, I call $Y$ *invariant* under the action if the morphism $\IG_m \times Y \into \IG_m \times X \to X$ factors over $Y \into X$.

**Proposition:** *The correspondence
$$\{\text{Closed subschemes of }X\} \iso \{\text{Ideals of }R\}$$
restricts to a bijective correspondence
$$\{\IG_m\text{-invariant closed subschemes of }X\} \iso \{\text{Homogeneous ideals of }R\}.$$*

For example if $Y$ is $\IG_m$-invariant, then by definition the given action restricts to an action of $\IG_m$ on $Y$ and the inclusion $Y \into X$ becomes a morphism of affine schemes with a $\IG_m$-action. Hence the surjective map $R=\sheaf{O}(X) \onto \sheaf{O}(Y)$ is a morphism of graded rings. But its kernel is $I$ which is, hence, homogeneous.

I was trying to prove the corresponding result for open subschemes:

**Conjecture 1:** *The correspondence
$$\{\text{Open subschemes of }X\} \iso \{\text{Radical ideals of }R\}$$
restricts to a bijective correspondence
$$\{\IG_m\text{-invariant open subschemes of }X\} \iso \{\text{Homogeneous radical ideals of }R\}.$$*

It is easy to see that a homogeneous radical ideal defines an invariant open subscheme. First note that the union of invariant open subschemes is again invariant. If the open subschemes $U_j$ are defined by $I_j$, then $\bigcup U_j$ is defined by $\sqrt{\sum I_j}$. Hence it suffices to consider $U = D(f)$ for $f$ a homogeneous element. But then it is easy to see that $U$ is invariant. In fact, the restricted action $\IG_m \times U \to U$ makes $U = \Spec(R[f^\inv])$ into an affine schemes with a $\IG_m$-action. The associated grading on $R[f^\inv]$ is the natural grading that you would expect on a localisation at a homogeneous element.

However I cannot mange to prove the converse, i.e. if $I$ is a radical ideal of $R$ such that the open subscheme $X_I \into X$ defined by $I$ is $\IG_m$-invariant then $I$ is homogeneous. By the proposition it would suffice to prove

**Conjecture 2:** *If $G$ is an (affine) group scheme acting on a scheme $X$ then the bijection
$$\{\text{Open subschemes of }X\} \iso \{\text{Reduced closed subschemes of }X\}$$
restricts to a bijection
$$\{G\text{-invariant open subschemes of }X\} \iso \{G\text{-invariant reduced closed subschemes of }X\}.$$*

This certainly sounds reasonable if one thinks for example of an action of a topological group on a topological space, where the complement of an invariant subset is clearly invariant again. However I cannot prove it and I'm not 100% sure that it is correct as a closed subscheme is more than just a certain subset.

If $G = \IG_m$ and $X$ is affine then this conjecture is equivalent to the first one.

My conjecture is also equivalent to the claim that if $U \subseteq X$ is an open $\IG_m$-invariant subscheme then $U$ is a union of subschemes of the form $D(f) \subseteq X$ where $f$ in $R$ is a homogeneous element. In particular, this would imply (a special case of) the following conjecture:

**Conjecture 3:** *If $G$ is an (affine) group scheme acting on a scheme $X$ and if $U \subseteq X$ is an open $G$-invariant subscheme then $G$ is a union of $G$-invariant affine open subschemes.*

Unfortunately I really don't have a good intuition for actions of groups schemes and I would be glad about some clarification.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "open subscheme defined by an ideal". (Typically, one says *closed* subschemes are defined by ideals, not *open* subschemes.)

Comment: @KReiser If you prefer the locally ringed spaces point of view, then the open subscheme $X_I$ of $X = \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ defined by an ideal $I$ of $R$ is given by the open subset $X_I = X \setminus V(I)$. This gives a bijection between radical ideals of $R$ and open subschemes of $X$. If you prefer the functorial view (which is certainly reasonable when dealing with group schemes) then $X_I \subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(R) = \mathrm{Hom}(R,{-})$ is given on $A$-valued points by $X_I(A) = \{ \alpha \colon R \to A \mid \langle \alpha(I)\rangle_A = \langle 1 \rangle_A\}$.

Comment: This is certainly a unique perspective - I'm not sure I've ever encountered someone espousing this viewpoint before. Anyways, typically one runs these arguments for closed subschemes, from which one could apply the correspondence between open subschemes and reduced closed subschemes given by putting the reduced induced structure on the complement of an open subscheme. (If you're not comfortable with this last step, I would recommend checking out the reduced induced subscheme structure on a closed subset - this should be helpful to you.)

Comment: @KReiser This correspondence between open subschemes and closed reduced subschemes given by „reduced closed complement“ is the one I'm referring to in the second of the three conjectures. If I could show that if an open subscheme is invariant, then its reduced closed complement is also invariant, then I would be happy.

Comment: Copy on mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351122